# Why my variable is true and not true at the same time?

Tags: javascript

Just take a look at this javascript:

```
localStorage.myAwesomeItem = true;
var item = localStorage.myAwesomeItem;
alert(item);
if(item==true)
    {alert("really true");}
else
    {alert("lies; not true");}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b29pztL7/1)

I set `myAwesomeItem` of the local storage to `true`. Fine. Then I store this item in a variable called `item`. And alert to check its value. As you see, it is `true`.

Then I check through the condition if my item is really true. But *it is not*. It goes for the `else`.

Can anyone explain me this behavior?

Comment: Because it's converted to a string in local storage.  And `"true" != true`

Comment: First thing I did was scratch my head ... then `alert(item.constructor.name);`. Ah-haaaa ....

Comment: @Jongware `alert(typeof(item))` did it for me :)

Comment: What kinda threw me for a loop is, he's using loose equal, so one will be converted to the type of the other, and in both cases the type conversion should make them equal. `!!'true' === true` and `true.toString() === 'true'`. But that's not the case here.

Comment: @KevinB Yes - I had to go double check, I thought it should be converted too at first

Comment: @Kevin so there is another explanation apart from ones which were already provided as answers?

Comment: No, i'm still curious why it works this way, even though I usually avoid these kinds of issues by storing the data as json and parsing it when i extract it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Local storage converts anything stored in into string. So you can get it working by doing this:

```
if(item=="true")...
```

Comment: You might want to add that it converted the `true´ to string-true in local storage as James thorpe pointed out.

Answer (score 6):

Localstorage stores everything as strings. So the true you input is actually saved as "true" and the false as "false".

All non-empty strings in javascript evaluate to true.

Comment: "All non-empty strings in javascript evaluate to true." Which is irrelevant when you compare a string and a boolean using ==. In that case, the boolean will be cast to a string before comparison, not the other way around.

Comment: A good point. I think i unconsciously thought of the way i would write an if of the truthyness of a value which would simply be if(value). That would obviously not work here though..

Comment: I disagree. If i want to check the truthyness of a string what im checking is whether the string is not undefined and is not empty. It has nothing to do whether the string is "true" or "false", which is why it would not work in the OP:s problem.